# Bootstrap 3 - columns won't center align

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to center align three Bootstrap columns. I do not want the columns to span the entire row. I think that will make the images look too big for the space. That is why I put three "col-md-3" columns. I prefer this size column. I just want the columns to center align. I thought that I could apply the class name, "justify-content-md-center" to the row and it would work but it is not working. Does anyone know how to center align the columns below, using Bootstrap 3? Is it possible?

**Here is my code:**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-md-center">

        <div class="col-md-3 text-center">
            <img alt="TBD" width="100%" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" />
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-3 text-center">
            <img alt="TBD" width="100%" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" />
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-3 text-center">
            <img alt="TBD" width="100%" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" />
        </div>

    </div><!-- end row -->
</div><!-- end container -->
```

View it on [CodePen](https://codepen.io/matie/pen/Jeezxb).

Thank you for helping!

Comment: Does it have to be Bootstrap 3? Because with Bootstrap 4 you can just add the class `mx-auto` to the `div.row` to make it's children centered.

Comment: Yes, it has to be Bootstrap 3.

Comment: Oh well. I think the problem here is that your 3 columns do not add up to 12, it add up to 9. It has to add up to 12 or else you'll have that missing `col-3` gap. Changing the column class to `col-4` should fix this.

Comment: Use md-4 and add right/left padding to the row?  Bootstrap 3 doesn't have anything native to do that, which is why `mx-auto` was added in 4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others have pointed out, change col-md-3 to col-md-4

> I do not want the columns to span the entire row. I think that will make the images look too big for the space.

the solution I know of for Bootstrap 3 is to add a `max-width` to a container so it doesn't stretch the full screen/element (without removing the 100% from the images as that would no longer make them resize/responsive).

You may also want to use col-sm-4 or col-sm-6  so they don't end up too big when the screen is smaller:

https://codepen.io/StudioKonKon/pen/yQQrdM

```css
.mycontent
{
   max-width: 800px; /* or something else */
}
```

```html
<!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">



<div class="container mycontent">
 <div class="row justify-content-md-center">

  <div class="col-md-4 text-center">
   <img alt="TBD" width="100%" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" />
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-4 text-center">
   <img alt="TBD" width="100%" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" />
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-4 text-center">
   <img alt="TBD" width="100%" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" />
  </div>

 </div><!-- end row -->
</div><!-- end container -->
```

Comment: Thank you for addressing my concern about the images looking too big... this is the most simple and clean solution, while still getting the visual I wanted. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

All you gotta do is change `col-md-3` to `col-md-4`. In Bootstrap, the numbers in a `div.row` has to add up to 12 including the use of offsets.

Also get rid of `width="100%"` from the columns because that will stretch your image and use the exact size image you need.

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/examples/grid/

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/XyyQVR

Comment: Whoops forgot to hit the save button. Fixed now, thanks!

Comment: That's better :) The only catch I can see is that the asker says: "*I do not want the columns to span the entire row. [...] That is why I put three `col-md-3`*", so `col-md-4` might not be what they want.

Comment: Updated again. Just gotta remove `width="100%"` and use the correct sized image and everything is golden!

Answer (score 0):

You can offset each column using the `col-md-offset-*` class in Bootstrap as follows:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">

        <div class="col-md-3 col-md-offset-1 text-center">
            <img alt="TBD" width="100%" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" />
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-3 col-md-offset-1 text-center">
            <img alt="TBD" width="100%" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" />
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-3 col-md-offset-1 text-center">
            <img alt="TBD" width="100%" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" />
        </div>

    </div><!-- end row -->
</div><!-- end container -->
```

The above method will add equal spaces between the relative columns.

Answer (score 0):

hope thats what you wanted  , you cant set the col width to 3 out of 12 and expect to get centered items so you have to set it a 4 (4*3=12)(full row width/3) and then you set the max-width of the container just like this https://codepen.io/Dadboz/pen/pQQBMR

```html
<!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">



<div class="container" style="max-width :760px">
 <div class="row d-flex justify-content-center">

  <div class="col-md-4  text-center">
   <img alt="TBD" width="100%" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" />
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-4 text-center">
   <img alt="TBD" width="100%" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" />
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-4 text-center">
   <img alt="TBD" width="100%" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" />
  </div>

 </div><!-- end row -->
</div><!-- end container -->
```

Answer (score 0):

For this I would use 2 rows, the first with an `-offset` (I used 8 with an offset of 2). Then change your 3 columns to span 4 instead of 3 to add up to 12.

Like this (using `xs` col size for demo):

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="container">

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-8 col-xs-offset-2">

      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-4 text-center">
          <img alt="TBD" width="100%" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" />
        </div>

        <div class="col-xs-4 text-center">
          <img alt="TBD" width="100%" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" />
        </div>

        <div class="col-xs-4 text-center">
          <img alt="TBD" width="100%" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" />
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- end row 2 -->

    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- end row 1 -->

</div>
<!-- end container -->
```